# Importing urllib2 or urllib

Tags: python, import, urllib2, urllib

I am getting weird input request thing "type number 1:>" when importing urllib or urllib2 modules in python (either using interpreter or from a file - though interpreter is intermittently encountering this issue but file is consistent)

```
$ python testurl.lib 
type number 1:>1
type number 2:>2
999
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testurl.lib", line 1, in <module>
import urllib2
File      "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
import httplib
File  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
import mimetools
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
import tempfile
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
from random import Random as _Random
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 45, in <module>
from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: cannot import name log
```

The output/error is same, no matter whether input '1' and '2' is given or no.

Tried on:

Python 2.7.10

Python 2.7.6

Both versions giving issue

Comment: show the code of `testurl.lib`.

Comment: Do you have a `math.py` in the same folder?

Comment: I bet @ChakerBenhamed is on the right track. Your problem isn't `urllib` or `urllib2`, it's `math`. Is it consistent for any script, or just testurl.lib?

Comment: Yes! That was it. I renamed math.py to something else and it is working fine now. But what math.py had to do with it?

Comment: @user3806770, as your issue has been solved, please accept one of the answers :).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was that you had a `math.py` file somewhere in your PYTHONPATH, which is the chain of directories that is searched when you import a module. It starts with your current working directory and the directory the script is in, so because you had a `math.py` file in one of those directories (maybe they were the same directory in this case), it was imported before the `math` module in the standard library.

**TLDR:** Never use names of standard library modules for your own modules, so you don't run into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `math.py` in the same folder.

When importing python look for the current folder, and when it found `math.py` it tries to import it before the math module.